# Is gnu screen actually freeing resources when I close a window within it?

Tags: linux, matlab, unix, console

Let's suppose we have this scenario: I open a session with the `screen` console multiplexer, then I open several window inside of it (Ctrl-a + C) to run, let's say, MATLAB tests.

When I kill just a single window, and consequently all the processes running in it, **is the system actually freeing the resources used by it?** Or are they still allocated for the whole session and not freed until I exit from the session?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **kill** just a single window, and **consequently all the processes running** that's your answer.

Comment: It's called 'gnu screen', and gnu is not unix.

Comment: You can check whether resources are freed by using Unix utilities including `ps`, `top`, `free`.